# Is there a way to format what fzf displays without formatting its output?

Tags: bash, fzf

I'm currently trying to write a script that takes a list of filenames with their absolute paths as input and feeds them to `fzf`. After making a selection, they are passed as command-line arguments etc. Something along the lines:

```
find $working_directory -type f | fzf -e | ...
```

Now, I do not want to see the absolute path of every file displayed by `fzf` as I feel it both looks ugly and makes it difficult to see the filenames. However, I do need the absolute paths for later on, so I do not just want to format them outright. Is there a way to format what `fzf` displays without formatting the output it generates?

Comment: If you still want a solution to this I guess I could help you but I need to understand correctly what you want.  In your case `find $working_directory -type f | fzf -e` will print  the relative paths (such as `./file.txt`,`./somedir/file.txt`, etc.). What you want is using the `absolute path` (e.g. `/home/user/file.txt`) after piping with `fzf -e`?

Comment: Provide the expected result you want and it will be useful to provide  what you want to pipe after `fzf -e |`

Comment: I want the paths to be trimmed from what is displayed by `fzf`, but keep the path after selection to provide the file to a pdf reader (in this case). 

Suppose `/path/to/file/doc.pdf` is a generic file that I will select through `fzf`. I want this file to be displayed as `doc.pdf` in `fzf`, but upon selecting, I want it to return `/path/to/file/doc.pdf`.

The complete command would be:
`zathura $(find $working_directory -type f | fzf -e)`

Comment: What about having these paths: `/path/to/file/doc.pdf` and `/path/to/file/subfile/doc.pdf`? In that case if you show only the basename it will be ambiguous to determine what path you used (unless you use an array to determine the path by its index)

Comment: Also to achieve that you want yo will have to be placed in the path of the file, for example: having this path: `/path/to/file/doc.pdf` you should be placed in `file` directory to be able to pipe the selected option to another command and parse it as you want (the full path)